# Why are trivial solutions "wrong"?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Why are trivial solutions "wrong"?

For example, if I'm solving a PDE and the eigenvalue being zero implies that the solution to the PDE is identically $0$, why do we say that the eigenvalue cannot equal $0$?

Comment: When did you hear that an eigenvalue cannot equal $0$?

Comment: They're not wrong, just not very interesting. If you assume that the eigenvalue ≠ 0, then you can use that assumption to find other solutions than the trivial ones.

Comment: The solution to a PDE (or any linear system) that is zero is not an eigensolution (or eigenvector).  Note that $0 = \lambda 0$ is true for any $\lambda$, so the zero solution does not help us to characterize what $\lambda$ can be.

Comment: 5xum that's not what I said.  I am referring specifically to PDE's, specifically to the heat equation with Neumann boundary conditions.

Comment: That's kind of what I mean.  It still solves it, even if it is "useless."

Comment: For a linear system, every value would be an eigenvalue if you did not require non-zero solutions. Every value would be an eigenvalue of a matrix, for example. Not a very interesting concept.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of eigenvalue requires that the associated eigenvector (or eigenfunction) be non-zero.